# text editing & saving in IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, rtf

I have a UITextview showing certain text by calling rtf files.
I want to let users to edit the text on UITextView and save the changes they made in rtf file.

Is there any way I can change the rtf file itself by changing the text on UITextView??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a save-as-you-type solution to the problem:

1. Make your view controller conform to `UITextViewDelegate`
2. Connect the text view's `delegate` to the view controller
3. Add the following function to your view controller:

---

```
// Path to your RTF file
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("my_document", withExtension: "rtf")!

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    let data = try! textView.attributedText.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, textView.attributedText.length), documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType])
    data.writeToURL(url, atomically: true)
}
```

This will save every keystroke to the file. No idea on the performance though. I have not tested this on a real iPhone. If it's too hard on the device, consider putting a time delay between saves or have an `NSTimer` to save every *n* seconds.

Comment: Sorry for late confirmation. I just tried and it works very well! I have a further question. Would there be any way I can revert the rtf file back to the original state when needed? The one way I can think is making two copies and letting users to just manipulate the second one.

Comment: You have to make a copy of the original file. Remember, every keystroke is a write to the file so you lose its previous state.